# Why is there a '.d' in 'init.d'?

Tags: filenames, lfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the .d stand for in directory names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/what-does-the-d-stand-for-in-directory-names)

Consider that we have (on many sytems) `init.d` that contains executable scripts and symbolic links for run levels, `sysctl.d` that contains text configuration files for kernel tuning on boot and `modprobe.d` that contains text configuration files to load kernel modules on boot. These are just examples.

What, precisely is the similarity between the contents of these locations that necessitates the `.d` suffix on the end of the directory? What would be an inappropriate use of it?

I've been using UNIX like operating systems for well over 15 years, and I found that I could not explain the significance of `.d` to someone today.

#### Addendum:

I *thought* it signified 'daemon', but neither modprobe nor sysctl would fit in that category.