# What does the "rc" stand for in /etc/rc.d?

Tags: linux, history

Does anybody have an idea about the full form of rc.d in, for example, `/etc/rc.d`?

It contains scripts to used to control the starting, stopping and restarting of daemons. But what exactly is the meaning of **rc** here?

Comment: Are you asking about the `at` command? Or about the directory? Please change your question so that "yes I have a clue" is not a correct (but useless) answer.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rc_file

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This goes pretty far back in the Unix history. `rc` stands for "run commands", and makes sense actually:

> rc
>
> runcom (as in .cshrc or /etc/rc)
>   The rc command derives from the runcom facility from the MIT CTSS system, ca. 1965. From Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie, as told to Vicki Brown:
>
> > "There was a facility that would **execute a bunch of commands stored in a file**; it was called runcom for "run commands", and the file began to be called "a runcom". rc in Unix is a fossil from that usage."

[Source](http://kb.iu.edu/data/abnd.html)

> The idea of having the command processing shell be an ordinary slave program came from the Multics design, and a predecessor program on CTSS by Louis Pouzin called RUNCOM, **the source of the ".rc" suffix on some Unix configuration files**. The first time I remember the name "shell" for this function was in a Multics design document by Doug Eastwood (of BTL). Commands that return a value into the command line were called "evaluated commands" in the original Multics shell, which used square brackets where Unix uses backticks.

([source](http://www.multicians.org/unix.html))

In summary, rc.d stands for "run commands" at runlevel which is their actual usage. The meaning of `.d` can be found here [What does the .d stand for in directory names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4029/41104)

Please don't mix up with rc the shell interpreter which was included in Plan 9, which were descendant of Bourne Shell.

Comment: and suffix **.d** means directory? Does it mean Run Command Directory?

Comment: @user3134198 http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4029/41104

Answer (score 11):

If you're asking what the meaning of the acronym `rc` is, according to the [jargon file](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/index.html), it derives from **runcom**:

> rc file: /R�C fi:l/, n. [Unix: from runcom files on the [CTSS](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/CTSS.html) system
>   1962-63, via the startup script /etc/rc] Script file containing
>   startup instructions for an application program (or an entire
>   operating system), usually a text file containing commands of the sort
>   that might have been invoked manually once the system was running but
>   are to be executed automatically each time the system starts up. See
>   also [dot file](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/dot-file.html), [profile](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/P/profile.html) (sense 1).

***Source**: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/R/rc-file.html*

#### Run levels

In version 7 Unix the `/etc/rc`'s were replaced with runlevels. So on a modern day Linux box you'll see this type of directory structure.

> The runlevel system replaced the traditional /etc/rc script used in Version 7 Unix.

***Source:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel*

```
$ ls -l
total 32
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 12:21 init.d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 12:21 rc0.d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 12:21 rc1.d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 12:21 rc2.d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 12:21 rc3.d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 12:21 rc4.d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 12:21 rc5.d
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Jan  3 12:21 rc6.d
```

Each of these directories represents a [runlevel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel). Different distros use these in slightly different ways. For example, on Red Hat based distros run level 3 is meant for running a system without a desktop, while 5 is meant for when running a desktop.

To designate that you wanted a particular service to start in one level vs. not in another you'd initially have to create links to the actual `rc` scripts for a particular service, naming the link in a special way. The links would look like this:

```
$ ls -l rc3.d/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 20 Dec  7 20:56 K50netconsole -> ../init.d/netconsole
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 18 Dec  7 20:56 K85ebtables -> ../init.d/ebtables
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 17 Dec  7 20:56 K90network -> ../init.d/network
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 28 Jan  3 12:21 S04dkms_autoinstaller -> ../init.d/dkms_autoinstaller
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15 Dec 14 22:57 S95jexec -> ../init.d/jexec
```

Names starting with a `K` meant that this service should be killed for this runlevel, while `S` meant that it should be started. The numbers after the `K` & `S` denoted what order the services should be killed and started.

In recent years this approach has started to wain in favor of 2 new technologies,[`systemd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) & [`upstart`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart).

Comment: So it means runcom files, right? Run Com, here com means configuration or what?

Comment: @user3134198 - Com would mean command files.