# rsyslog versus rsyslog.d

Tags: rhel, logs, rsyslog

I'm currently studying for my Red Hat Certification exam, and I've come across an example in my book dealing with system log architecture. I'm currently working a classroom RHEL7 environment.

My question is about the syntax but here is the lab so you have all of the info:

I am asked to configure rsyslogd so that it records syslog messages to authentication and security issues that have priority alert or higher to the file /var/log/auth-errors. I'm asked to use the file /etc/rsyslog.d/auth-errors.conf to do this, creating the file if necessary.

Can anyone explain to me the significance of the d? I'm confused about the difference between rsyslogd, rsyslog.d and rsyslog.

My guess is that the d signifies a daemon but I'd like to be sure.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Everything that you should know for this is already in chapter 13 if you're using Sander his book.

Comment: I'm not using the book  you referenced.

Comment: @hspaans the good old rtfm answer

Comment: I'd say this is duplicate question with : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4029/what-does-the-d-stand-for-in-directory-names

Comment: @Tristan no a reference to where it is documented instead of duplicating copyrighted text. That is also why it was a comment and not an answer to the question.

Comment: Yes you are not supposed but supposed to put only link to external content which can expire on SO (book no more published for example). see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23628/how-should-we-deal-with-rtfm-comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rsyslogd` is the rsyslog daemon, an open source implementation of syslog, and has replaced `syslogd` in newer systems. Here the final `d` means indeed *daemon*.

`/etc/rsyslog.d/` is just the directory where rsyslog's configuration files are kept. Rsyslog, just like the majority of the services nowadays, uses split configuration files (one file for each source) as opposed to a big configuration file containing all the sources.  If you take a look into `/etc/` you will find that many other services are organized in a similar way, for instance `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`.